# Reverse Propel ORM results in 'Buildfile: /build.xml does not exist'

Tags: php, propel

When calling the following command from within a folder with build.properties file in it

```
# ../propel/generator/bin/propel-gen . reverse
```

I get

> Buildfile: /build.xml does not exist!

Is this because I calling the propel-gen file incorrectly as it should be in my PATH?

Or is there another reason?

I didn't think that using reverse even needed a build.xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything needs a `build.xml` file as it's how Phing works. But, it should be auto discovered in `.../propel/generator`. This issue is known and has been fixed in Propel after 1.6.7.